# Python says syntax error for an elif statement

Tags: if-statement, python-3.x, syntax, syntax-error

```
flag=False
if color1=="blue":
    color2=input("Do you want to mix red or yellow with blue?")
    color2=color2.lower()
    while flag==False:
        if color2=="red" or color2=="yellow":
            flag = True
        else:
            color2=input("That is not a valid choice. Enter either red or yellow to mix\ with", color1)
    if color2=="red":
        print("The color you made is purple")
    else:
        print("The color you made is green")
flag=False
elif color1=="red":
    color2=input("Do you want to mix blue or yellow with red?")
    color2=color2.lower()
    while flag==False:
        if color2=="blue" or color2=="yellow":
            flag = True
        else:
            color2=input("That is not a valid choice. Enter either blue or yellow to\ mix with", color1)
```

I'm getting a problem with the one elif statement toward the middle on the line that says "elif color1=="red":". And just to get some context, this is a simple program that will mix three primary colors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the indentation in your program is the same as it appears in your question, the line `flag=False` immediately before the `elif` needs to be indented, or else the parser will think that you've left the `if` block when you in fact haven't.

Comment: Thank youuuu! I never knew this! You have no idea how relieved i am; i spent almost 30 minutes trying to solve that. ^-^